# How to disable event during a state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Since my code base is quite big I will not add an example. Hopefully my question is clear enough.

I am using react-chartjs-2 in order to create a doughnut chart. I notice that every state change will probably trigger and event on the chart. I can’t figure it out  how to prevent the chart from render.

Any idea how to disable this behavior ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that if your component does not render it will not trigger a rerender in your chart, you could wrap your chart in a new component and use `React.memo` with your condition to render or not the chart, but take to avoid rendering bugs with `memo` it would be your last option used for performance improvements.

> React is VERY fast and there are so many things I can think of for you
> to do with your time that would be better than optimizing things like
> this

Kent C. Dodds
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a function Component you could use hooks like [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) which prevent you from rendering certain child components from rerendering. If you are using a class component you could get use of life cycle [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)